# garbage value after calling a member function of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, fstream, member-functions

I was trying to call a member of class a from class b but was unsuccessful it works but always gives garbage value for the vector in class a and yes the exception is thrown on the third time while the read loop is only supposed to run only 2 times.

b.h

```
 #pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;

class b {
    fstream fio;
    string s;
    a aio;
public:
    b(string);
    b( b& );
    void all(string);
    void out();
    void reset();
    ~b();
};
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"

b::b(string in)
    :fio{ "see.bin",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app }, s{ in }
{
}

b::b( b& bi ) 
    : fio{ "see.bin",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app }, s{ bi.s }
{   
}

void b::all(string in) {
    s = in;
    reset();
    aio.set_n( s );             //n is a string in a class
    aio.set_s( 11 );             // s is a size_t object in a class
    aio.set_v( 114 );            // v is the vector in a class
    fio.write( ( char* )&aio, sizeof( aio ) );
    reset();
}

void b::out() {
    reset();
        while (fio.read( ( char* )&aio, sizeof( aio )  //read function gone rouge 
            aio.print();
}

void b::reset() {
    fio.clear();
    fio.seekg( 0, ios_base::beg );
}

b::~b() {
    fio.close();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "b.h"


int main() {
    b obj_1( "" );
    obj_1.all( "xyz" );
    obj_1.out();

}
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

a::a()
    :s{ 0 }
{
}

a::a( a& ai )
    : s{ ai.s }, n{ ai.n }
{
    for (auto c : ai.v)
        v.push_back( c );
}

a::a( a&& ai ) noexcept
    :s{ ai.s }, n{ ai.n }
{
    for (auto c : ai.v)
        v.push_back( c );
    ai.v.clear();
}

void a::set_v( int i ) {v.push_back( i );}

void a::set_s( size_t si ) {    s = si;}

void a::set_n( string na ) {n = na;}


void a::print(){
    cout << s << " " << n << " ";
    for (int &p : v)
        cout << " " << p;
}

a::~a() {v.clear();}
```

for reference a is a class having a copy constructor,  move constructor ,normal constructor  ,all the setters for each object and an destructor. 
Thank you for helping me and reading my badly written code.

Comment: Where is the definition of `a`? Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i'll try my best to keep it as short as possible i added definition of a if necessary and please tell me if you need .h file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-[POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) types cannot be directly written or read. For example, the std::string class. The string class has some member data, but commonly, the string content is elsewhere (like in dynamic memory).

I would suggest define the `<<` and `>>` operator for your class to serialize and un-serialize.

The [`Boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library handles this rather elegantly. I've used it in several projects. There's an example program, showing how to use it, [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp).

The only native way to do it is to use streams. That's essentially all the `Boost::serialization` library does, it extends the stream method by setting up a framework to write objects to a text-like format and read them from the same format.

For built-in types, or your own types with `operator<<` and `operator>>` properly defined, that's fairly simple; see [the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-simple-types) for more information.

See also [Qt serialization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html) and [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)

**EDIT: **

Try this but this is not portable and it doesn't handle all of the corner cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>

class Bin {

public:
    void set_size(size_t s)                 { size_ = s; }
    void set_str(const std::string& s)      { str_ = s; }
    void append_int(int s)                  { vec_.emplace_back(s); }

public:
    size_t get_size(void) const             { return size_; }
    std::string get_str(void) const         { return str_; }
    std::vector<int> get_vec(void) const    { return vec_; }

public:
    void print(void) const
    {
        std::cout << "---- A ----" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size: " << size_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Str: " << str_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Vec: ";
        for (const auto& i: vec_)
            std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-----------" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& fstream, const Bin& obj)
    {
        size_t str_size = obj.str_.length();
        size_t vec_size = obj.vec_.size();
        fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&obj.size_), sizeof(obj.size_));
        fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&str_size), sizeof(str_size));
        for (const auto& i: obj.str_)
            fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&i), sizeof(i));
        fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&vec_size), sizeof(vec_size));
        for (const auto& i: obj.vec_)
            fstream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&i), sizeof(i));
        return fstream;
    }

public:
    friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& fstream, Bin& obj)
    {
        obj.str_.clear();
        obj.vec_.clear();
        size_t size = 0;

        fstream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&obj.size_), sizeof(obj.size_));
        fstream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), sizeof(size));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            char c;
            fstream.read(&c, sizeof(c));
            obj.str_.push_back(c);
        }
        fstream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size), sizeof(size));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int j;
            fstream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&j), sizeof(j));
            obj.vec_.emplace_back(j);
        }
        return fstream;
    }

private:
    size_t size_;
    std::string str_;
    std::vector<int> vec_;
};

int main(void)
{
    Bin a, b;
    a.set_size(100);
    a.set_str("stackoverflow");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        a.append_int(i + 1);
    a.print();
    {
        std::ofstream ostream("see.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        ostream << a;
    }

    std::ifstream istream("see.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    istream >> b;
    b.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping, since I am using binary file should I use operator overloading or just the read and write function?

Comment: hey I tried using the read method in the overloaded operator and it worked but the only issue with that was it gave an error whenever the destructor of a was called. Can you please tell why because I don't want to use serialization yet, anyways thanks for the help.(edit: it is probably due to the deletion of the string in a)(void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() // this function gives an exception in xmemory)

Comment: See an example in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot to all it worked.  i used operator overloading on >> and << operator with custom input i was able to input the vector and string in file then get it back thanks a lot for helping me.